# How to find all files in one directory that match files in other directory in gulp using del?

Tags: gulp, glob

Basically, as part of my clean task, I'd like to delete in the root folder all files that are present in my src folder, automatically. Because there are files in the root that aren't in src, I can't just delete all of them, and I'd like to keep the process dynamic (automatically determine matching files) rather than manual (explicitly listing the files to delete).

Right now, I'm doing this manually:

```
const deleteViewFiles = done => {
  del.sync([
    './page-*.php',
    './header.php',
  ]);
  done();
}
```

But what I'd like is, look at `./src/views/`, find all direct descendants of `./src/views/` (not subfolders), and delete them at the root.

eg. Let's say in `./src/views/` I have `page-1.php`, `header.php`, `my-dog.php`, `mermaid.html`, I want to delete all those files from root without listing them in my delete task.

Comment: If that's regex the the first one translates to: any char, forward slash, page, zero or more dashes, any char, php. Somehow I doubt that what you wanted...

Answer (score 0):

OK. Here's what I ended up doing.

I used `glob` to store all files in my src directory into an array.

Then, I replaced the view folder base path with root base path. Then I used this array as an argument for my del function.

```
(I stored paths in a config file, here's a snippet (the real object is much bigger):)
paths = {
  views: {
    src: `${dirs.src}views/`,
    dest: `${dirs.base}views/`,
    rootFiles: `${dirs.src}views/*.*`,
    folders: `${dirs.src}views/*/*`
  }
}

import { paths } from '../config';

const clean = done => {
  // get all files at root of views directory
  const viewsDirRootFiles = glob.sync(paths.views.rootFiles);

  // replace views dir in base of filepaths with root
  const rootFiles = viewsDirRootFiles.map(f => f.replace(paths.views.src, paths.dirs.base));

  // combine root view files with other folders/files to delete to generate final deletion-target array
  const filesToDelete = [
    ...rootFiles,
    './views',
  ];

  del.sync(filesToDelete);
  done();
}
```